# Abstractions in React - HOC and hooks, possible or am I just hitting the limitations of React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks

Say I have a create (POST) / update (PUT) endpoint for 10 (and growing) different resources.

All 10 of these resources implement the same popup form for create and update, design and flow wise.

Writing a `CreateFirstForm` `UpdateFirstForm` `CreateSecondForm` `UpdateSecondForm` is becoming super tedious. It's basically copy-pasta except the endpoint, fields and labels in the UI. They also all have "useCreateResource" and "useUpdateResource" hooks incorporated that are basically calls to react-query's `useQuery` (calls fetch and manages state for the incoming / outgoing data)

So, I think, let's write a higher order component, that's what they are for, to abstract away common logic.

I initially thought I could parse the `id` in the URL to discern whether or not the call is a POST vs PUT.

It was all going well, code-wise, until I hit the dreaded `Hook is called conditionally` issue. The hook in question is basically `id ? useGetResource(id) : { }`  which determines the initial data a form should edit (existing vs blank).

Yes I understand I could separate this "upsert" flow into Create and Update flows starting with `CreateForm` and `UpdateForm` thereby bypassing all conditional hooks... but then it completely defeats my intention of abstracting away redundant code and I'm left with where I started at, 20 different form components for 10 different resources.

I realize this might be easier to understand with examples so here's some pseudocode with the interface of how I would like it to behave with one resource, a recipe.

```
// hooks
useGetRecipe = () => {}
useCreateRecipe = () => {}
useUpdateRecipe = () => {}
useUpsertRecipe = (id?) => {
  const recipe = id ? useGetRecipe(id) : {};
  const submit = // do the create vs update
  return {
    recipe,
    submit,
    ...
  }
}



// Components

// the Higher order component, takes in the form, the hook and edits the recipe in place. Submission will call submit with the updated data

const upsertResource = (FormComponent) => (hook) => () => {
   const id = useUrlParams('id') //presence or not should determine POST vs PUT
   const { recipe, submit } = hook(id);
   
   return <FormWrapper data={recipe} submit={submit}><FormComponent/></FormWrapper>
} 

//edits a recipe, mapping name attr to property in recipe

const RecipeForm = () => {
  return <Field name="name" />
}

// The top level component, which basically calls the HOC with the hook. All it would take for every resource if conditional hooks were allowed!

const UpsertRecipe = () => {
  const Upsert = upsertResource(RecipeForm)(useUpsertRecipe)
  return <Upsert><RecipeForm/></Upsert>
}
```

So using the above I should be able to keep 10 resources into 10 forms in which simply having "id" or not could determine a create vs update, but alas, hooks cannot be called conditionally.

Now, I started breaking up the "upsert" into create vs update.... but I just realized I'm back where I started, having 2 forms for each resource thereby making my HOC / custom hook pattern useless, which is fine, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do stuff like this or should I just toss it up to, "it's just UI... sometimes we write repeated code."

Thanks!

Comment: Why not create a hook that knows whether or not it is an update or create by passing in a possibly undefined id argument?   Then you just call submit or save and internally that hook determines the save strategy based on the existence of that id?

Comment: @ScottZ the update/create calls also unfortunately have hooks inside them that sooner or later gets called conditionally, based on the ID. useQuery from react-query, for example.

Comment: The strategy hook would import the create/update/upsert hooks and return a function that could internally determine which method to call based on whatever criteria you are currently using.  No need to conditionally instantiate a hook.  Just conditionally use the method it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the strategy hook I envision.

```
const useUpdateStrategy = () => {
  const getId = useGetRecipie();
  const update = useUpdateRecipie();
  const create = useCreateRecipie();

  const updateStrategy = async (id, data) => {
    const recipieId = id ? await getId(id) : undefined;
    if (recipieId) {
      return update({
        id,
        data
      })
    }
    return create({
      data
    })
  }
  return {
    updateStrategy
  }
}
```

With this, you would only need to call `updateStrategy` on form submittal and either pass an id or not, plus whatever form data you have.

Comment: Or you could pass the id directly to `useUpdateStrategy` and then you'd only need to pass the form data to `updateStrategy`

Comment: Thanks this works, didnt even think to just cache it and use whatever result based on the condition.. Only issue is then it makes unnecessary network calls, but I could update the useApi hook I have to handle that (dont call it if ID is undefined or something).